# How to pass a variable from my jquery as POST to new page that opens

Tags: jquery

I need help in resolving this. I have jquery that adds new row, but I need to POST the ammount of rows added to new page. When the "form" is submitted.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var b=1;
  $("a[name=addRow]").click(function() {
    b=b+1;
    $("table#myTable tr:last").after("<tr><td style='text-align:left;'class='Default'>
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime that you add a new row increment the value of a hidden input field and simply submit that with your form.

You can do something like:

```
$("a[name=addRow]").click(function() {
    b=b+1;
    $("#hidden_input").val(b);
.....
```

And add this in your form tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="row_count" id="hidden_input" />
```